# yaml-cpp compiler errors when trying to build library

Tags: yaml-cpp

I'm trying to compile [yaml-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/) 0.5 using Visual Studio Express 2012 (using the Cmake-generated project files) and I'm getting some errors from impl.h:

```
error C2734: 'lhs' : const object must be initialized if not extern
error C2027: use of undefined type 'YAML::convert<T>'
error C3861: 'decode': identifier not found
error C3861: 'encode': identifier not found
```

All of the errors are coming from the template functions `node_data::equals` and `node_data::convert_to_node`

Note that these errors are coming from the `run-tests` project file; I am actually able to build the lib files but can't use the library since it needs these functions in order to work.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I also get the same errors when compiling with VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I just reported an isse and included a fix for this.

Please check http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=182

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010 strings are of type `const char[]` and that causes this compile error.
For me quick fix was to cast it into `char*`

```
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("Config.cfg");
int value = 0;
if (config[(char*)"value"])
    config[(char*)"value"].as<int>();
```

Doesn't look nice but will work till a fix from the library will come.